# Add Custom TextboxCell to a DataGridView control that contains a button to open the FileDialog

Tags: .net, .net-2.0

I would like to add a DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell to a DataGridViewCell control, but as well as being able to type in the text cell as normal it must also contain a '...' button that once clicks brings up the OpenFileDialog window to allow the user to select a file. Once selected, the text cell will be populated with the full file path.

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/7tas5c80.aspx) MSDN article explains how to add a custom control to a `DataGridView`.

You should be able to make a `UserControl` that has a textbox and button on it and embed that in the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Like this, perhaps http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/e2ec833b-be5a-4f0e-b11b-2d5354c2bf59

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own column and cell classes in order to do this. I would suggest using **.NET** Reflector to look at the implementation details of the DataGridViewTextBox as a starting point and then customizing to add display of a button at the end of it. Check out these tutorials to get started...

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882(VS.80).aspx)

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180996.aspx)